# Python pandas Recording dividend information from yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Other than pull OHLC, volume and adjusted close from the Datareader, Is there a way to capture the previous ex dividend dates and the dividend price using methods in `pandas.io.data`?

If not is the best way to pull dividend data using the `request` library and codes from [here](https://ilmusaham.wordpress.com/tag/stock-yahoo-data/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas now supports pulling dividend information from yahoo finance.

```
from pandas_datareader import data

data.DataReader('PFF', 'yahoo-actions') # returns dividend history for ticker PFF
```

Comment: Does it support companies not listed on US exchanges? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to capture the previous ex dividend dates and the
>   dividend price using methods in pandas.io.data?

No, this is not supported at the moment.

> If not is the best way to pull dividend data using the request library and codes from here?

The best way is undefined but that looks like a sensible approach to me (it is how I would go about it).